# Взаимодействие между классами без наследования

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть `BaseClass`:

```
// BaseClass.h
#pragma once
#include "ChildClass.h"
class BaseClass
{
public:
    BaseClass();
    ~BaseClass();
    ChildClass obj;
};

// BaseClass.cpp
#include "BaseClass.h"
BaseClass::BaseClass()
{
}
BaseClass::~BaseClass()
{
}
```

Есть `ChildClass`:

```
// ChildClass.h
#pragma once
#include "BaseClass.h"
class ChildClass
{
public:
    ChildClass(BaseClass &obj);
    ~ChildClass();
    BaseClass obj;
};

// ChildClass.cpp
#include "ChildClass.h"
ChildClass::ChildClass(BaseClass &obj)
{
    this->obj = obj;
}
ChildClass::~ChildClass()
{
}
```

**Описание:** в конструктор `ChildClass` передается ссылка на объект `BaseClass` и инициализируется внутренний объект базового класса, который расположен в дочернем классе. В базовом классе же обявляется поле, которое должно ссылаться на впоследствии инициализированный объект дочернего класса. Т.е. грубо говоря нужно чтобы дочерний класс имел доступ к своему объекту через базовый класс.

**Вопрос:** такая архитектура вполне работала в `.NET-е`, что не нравится плюсам и как можно обойти проблему? В плюсах - данный пример не компилируется, VS выдает разнообразные ошибки, номера ошибок: `C2061`, `C2146`, `C4430`.

p.s. насколько я понял, учитывая мои скудные познания в плюсах, там существует какая то рекурсивная зависимость заголовочных файлов и не совсем понятно почему дериктива препроцессора `#pragma once` не срабатывает.

p.p.s. решение в этом ответе из комментариев: [Включение файлов C++.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/289504/%d0%92%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-c) - костыль (причем с сильными ограничениями), есть какое либо нормальное решение?

Comment: Господа, кто любит ставить минусы вопросам - минусами проблему не решить. Вы хотя бы аргументируйте в комментариях свои действия. Есть факт - данный код отлично работал в .NET, как его портировать на плюсы?

Comment: Пожалуйста, укажите в чем проблема которую необходимо обойти.

Comment: @Cerbo, нужно реализовать следующее поведение: в дочерние классы передается через конструкторы объект базового класса, объекты дочерних классов инициализируются в конструкторе базового класса. Из любого дочернего класса есть доступ к объекту другого дочернего класса. Проблема именно в этом, как правильно реализовать подобное? В моем случае пример - не компилируется, происходят разнообразные ошибки.

Comment: То что привели не является проблемой, это ваша цель. Проблема это что мешает вам достигнуть цели. Пожалуйста, опишите проблему.

Comment: @Cerbo, пример просто напросто не компилируется, студия выдает разнообразные ошибки. Если нужно приведу номера ошибок.

Comment: В вопросе это должно быть указано, а не в комментариях.

Comment: @Cerbo добавил, но сути это не меняет.

Comment: @Cerbo, в том ответе описан костыль (причем с сильными ограничениями), есть какое либо нормальное решение?

Comment: Это кресты, привыкайте. В шарпе объекты классов являются ссылками поэтому этот костыль работает по-умолчанию. Попробуйте сделать такое со структурами.

Comment: @Cerbo, структуры практически не использую, только в крайне узких местах (собственная реализация MD5 и т.д.), поэтому это было не очевидно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот, развитие идеи @Abyx в коде (простите, в комментарий не помещается...)

```
// BaseClass.h
#pragma once
#include "ChildClass.h"

class ChildClass;

class BaseClass
{
public:
    BaseClass(ChildClass&obj);
    ~BaseClass();
    ChildClass * obj;
};

// BaseClass.cpp
#include "BaseClass.h"
BaseClass::BaseClass(ChildClass&obj)
{
    this->obj = &obj;
}
BaseClass::~BaseClass()
{
}

// ChildClass.h
#pragma once
#include "BaseClass.h"

class BaseClass;

class ChildClass
{
public:
    ChildClass(BaseClass &obj);
    ~ChildClass();
    BaseClass * obj;
};

// ChildClass.cpp
#include "ChildClass.h"
ChildClass::ChildClass(BaseClass &obj)
{
    this->obj = &obj;
}
ChildClass::~ChildClass()
{
}
```

Вот второй вариант - работа через ссылки:

```
// BaseClass.h
#pragma once
#include "ChildClass.h"

class ChildClass;

class BaseClass
{
public:
    BaseClass(ChildClass&obj);
    ~BaseClass();
    ChildClass& obj;
};

// BaseClass.cpp
#include "BaseClass.h"
BaseClass::BaseClass(ChildClass&obj):obj(obj)
{
}
BaseClass::~BaseClass()
{
}

// ChildClass.h
#pragma once
#include "BaseClass.h"

class BaseClass;

class ChildClass
{
public:
    ChildClass(BaseClass &obj);
    ~ChildClass();
    BaseClass& obj;
};

// ChildClass.cpp
#include "ChildClass.h"
ChildClass::ChildClass(BaseClass &obj):obj(obj)
{
}
ChildClass::~ChildClass()
{
}
```

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнить, а как именно объявляются объекты классов, если они зависимы друг от друга, можете привести пример?

Comment: Ну, например, http://vpaste.net/fte34

Answer (score 4):

Член `ChildClass::obj` должен быть ссылкой или указателем.
И `ChildClass` должен инициализироваться в конструкторе `BaseClass`.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, минимальный пример.